# Git merge merge all tracking files(snapshot) or changed files?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Assuming we have three files 1 2 3 and they all have initial value 6 in each file (commit a)

- In branch 1, commits: a(666),b(166),c(126) d(663)
- In branch 2, commits: a(666),e(777)

Where:

- b change file1 6 to 1
- c change file2 6 to 2
- d change file1 file2 back to 6 and file3 to 3
- e change file1 file2 file3 to 7

When I merge branch 1 into branch2, only file3 has merge conflict?
Why is that?

My understanding is that commits `d` and commit `e` will merge all tracking files together so that all files should have merge conflicts?

Comment: I'm curious... what do the files look like after the merge? 7,7,conflict?

Comment: As far as the diff algorithm is concerned, the only file that is different between the two branches is file 3, so I'm not surprised that the intermediate changes to files 1 and 2 on branch 1 are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge conflict generally occur on *concurrent* modifications (on the same lines of a file).

In your sequence of changes, only file3 was modified both in branch1 and branch2.
So it make sense the merge will:

- report (merge) modification from branch1 to branch2, where commit `d` reverted changes for `a` and `b` (back to 6): the merge consists to keep their modifications from branch2.
- detect a conflict for file3, which was modified in:

  - commit d (branch1)
  - commit e (branch2)